# Java Regular Expressions with String replace

Tags: java, regex

I Need help with Java Regular Expressions?

I have a String `"TA520"` and `"TA011"` and I want to get the number without the leading digit using regular expressions. So I need the `"520"` and the `"11"` without the leading `0` digits. I have the expression `aString = aString.replace("TA0* , "");` but this doesn't work. How would I do this with regular expressions in Java? Thank you.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `String.replace` does not use regular expressions.

You need to use `String.replaceAll`.

```
aString.replaceAll("^TA0*", "")
```

or alternatively, using `replaceFirst`:

```
aString.replaceFirst("^TA0*", "")
```

This strips away the leading "TA" plus any optional leading zeros.